# Call internal-sftp as shell call after ChrootDirectory in ForceCommand script

Tags: linux, ssh, shell, sftp

In my `SSH / SFTP` implementations, for a certain group of users, I'd like said users to be restricted to their `home` folders after login, and check for some other conditions before granting `SFTP` accessibility.

Restricting users to their home directories was simple enough, I added :

```
Match group <someGroup>
ChrootDirectory     %h
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

However, moving on to the second part, I want to check for certain conditions, this involved replacing `internal-sftp` in `ForceCommand` with a script.

Within the script, after the check :

```
sh -c $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

resolves to `/usr/libexec/openssh/sftp-server`, since that is the request sent by any `SFTP` client such as `WinSCP` (it's probably default..). While the user is able to use SFTP, the ability to `Chroot` the user to his / her home directory is gone.

I am not sure how to Force or call, from the shell script, the `internal-sftp` command, and `Chroot-ing` a user to his `%HOME` within the script. How shall I go about it, if indeed it is possible?

**UPDATE**

As per the answer below, I tried to copy the required system files to `Chroot` directory, and call `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` in my script.

**`sshd_config`**

```
Match group <somegroup>
ChrootDirectory     %h
ForceCommand    /usr/local/bin/testssh.sh
```

**`testssh.sh script`**

```
#! /bin/bash
sh -c $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND
```

**`ChrootDirectory (user home, complete path owned by root)`**

```
Contents
/bin
/etc
/lib
```

However, the user is still unable to initiate the sftp session. What else may be required?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot.

`internal-sftp` is a configuration keyword not a binary. It tells `sshd` to run SFTP server built-into `sshd`. You cannot call back to a running process from a shell command.

I believe that the `sftp-server` binary is retained specifically for scenarios like this, where `internal-sftp` cannot be used.
See my answer to [OpenSSH: Difference between internal-sftp and sftp-server](https://serverfault.com/q/660160/168875).

You should be able to do with `sftp-server`, it may just need more setup.

Comment: Actually, I had just been reading that link. `sftp-server` executed in script at `sh -c $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` works fine. Of course, isn't jailed. The link, "https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config#ChrootDirectory" says some files are required for in the `chroot-directory`, and mentions some, though I'm not sure if they are only for `SSH` or `SFTP`. Could you tell me which files ought to be there within the user profile (if $HOME is the chroot directory), and where to specify the Chroot (sshd_config or script)? Most links generally advise changing `sftp-server` subsystem to `internal-sftp`..

Comment: Chrooting should work with `sftp-server`. It just needs the support files. So I'm surprised that you can login, but the session is not chrooted. I would actually expect that you won't be able to login (as you do not have the support files).

Comment: On the above...Isn't `/usr/local/bin/sftp-server` the default `susbsystem`, which allows normal login? So, in the absence of a ForceCommand directive to `internal-sftp`, `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` which resolves to `sftp-server`, since that is what was sent, would allow normal login, like what is happening here, without any extra support files being present? Haven't used the `ChrootDirectory` yet in this scenario, since that would require support files, which I haven't copied over yet, not sure which files need to be copied...

Comment: I also (cheekily) tried to chain commands, used `ForceCommand <script.sh> && $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`, script would evaluate and send a 0, which would then cause original command to run - that worked fine. I then tried replacing `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` with `internal-sftp` there itself (with `Chroot`), didn't work...even though it's in the same `ForceCommand` directive. I changed the order `ForceCommand internal-sftp && <script.sh>` - SFTP worked and was jained, but the script didn't evaluate....

Comment: I got lost in your first comment. + As for the `ForceCommand` with `&&`. The `script && internal-sftp` cannot work as I have explained already. The `internal-sftp && script` works due to the way the `ForceCommand` is interpreted. `sshd` only checks if `ForceCommand` *starts* with `internal-sftp ` and uses the rest of the command (`&& script`) as its arguments. Which are probably silently ignored, as `sftp-server`/`internal-sftp` do not take any anonymous arguments.

Comment: Ah, first comment was just to point out that in the script, having `sh -c $SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` was allowing me to log in, but of course it wasn't jailed, and there was no `chroot` directive in `sshd_config`. For the main issue - `chroot` with `sftp-server`, I copied the `/lib`, `/etc`, and `/bin/sh, /bin/sftp, /bin/scp` to `chroot` directory, which is `%h` specified in `sshd_config`, but still `sftp` session doesn't initiate. What else should I be copying?

Comment: Updated question...

Comment: I have no experience with chrooting `sftp-server`. – Anyway, did you double-check what is in `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND`? It can contain `internal-sftp`.

Comment: With `sshd_config` containing `ChrootDirectory`, my test script doesn't even get executed, there are `echo` commands inside the script which should print the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` to a log, but nothing gets printed. If I don't have `ChrootDirectory` in `sshd_config`, then user logs in, and I can see the `SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` gets printed as `sftp-server`. The `sftp-server` file is not present in `chroot` - it's present in `/usr/libexec/openssh`. Should that be copied into the `chroot` as well? `chroot` contains `/bin/sftp`...

Comment: I would try that (copying `sftp-server` to chroot). But you probably need `testssh.sh` in the chroot in the first place.

Comment: So, I copied `usr/libexec/openssh` to `home\<user>\openssh` (/home/<user> is chroot directory mentioned in sshd_config). I also copied the test script to `chroot` directory. `bin, etc, lib, openssh` are root owned with access privilege to others. Test script is present in chroot, and mentioned in `sshd_config`, but whether owned by `root` or `user` (`chmod a+x `is done on it) - Still no change. Can't start a session. Script does not get executed. If I remove the `ChrootDirectory` in 'sshd_config`, then it works, but of course, not jailed...

Comment: If I do a `chroot` inside the script,  as `chroot $HOME $HOME/openssh/sftp-server`, at least WinSCP gives a different error - 125. Not sure what OpenSSH error 125 actually means.